# Extend DataSet Class Fill From SqlDataAdapter

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
class InspectionEquip : DataSet
{
    private readonly SqlConnection CPEC = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ToString());

    public InspectionEquip(string store)
    {
        CPEC.Open();
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("Select * From Equip3 Where Store = '" + store + "'", CPEC);
        SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(comm);
        da.Fill(/* What to Put Here? Tried "this" and it just returns blank */);    
        CPEC.Close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is vulnerable to SQL Injection - please read this: http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#SQL_injection

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  But the store argument is not coming from the user. Is there another danger I am overlooking?

Comment: @jmease It doesn't cost anything to use parameterized inputs, and it ends all possibility of SQL injection, so you should probably do it.

Comment: @jmease Besides best practices, is there any chance that this "store" field could contain a single quote? Your code will exception if it does.

Comment: No.  The store parameter is uniform.  Never contains any characters other than D, H, 0 - 9.

Comment: @jmease Just checking! There's still a performance hit (if you're using SQL Server at least) - see the [Query plans](http://www.sommarskog.se/dynamic_sql.html#queryplans) section on the same link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a problem with your SQL query (*no matching data, bad parameter*). `da.Fill(this)` works fine.

If you want proof - swap this [`SqlCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.aspx) line with yours...

```cs
SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand("select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", CPEC);
```

You should also probably extend [`DataTable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx), not [`DataSet`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dataset.aspx) if you only ever plan on storing a single tables results.

Comment: Thanks.  The SQL statement works fine.  I found the problem and it was my own stupidity.  Made a mistake in binding the DataSet to my DataGrid.  It's working now.